# Hover content covering sibling div as well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three images in an `inline-block` state. Whenever I hover over those images, I want a **black-overlay** opacity to **appear only over the images**. I re-worked my code around to put my descriptions for the images inside of the `div.home-image-blocks`, in order for me to be able to modify this in different viewports.

**Question:**
I am unsure of why black-overlay is covering the content from the `div.home-img-wording-blocks` blocks containers when I have the hover only applying to the `img`. I also have `max-height` set to 100% and `overflow: hidden`.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong with this for the hover effect to display over the content below and for the hover to allow the image to grow past the normal viewpoint?

```js
$('.home-img-block img').addClass(function() {
  return (this.width / this.height > 1) ? 'wide' : 'tall';
});
```

```css
#home-img-block-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 900px;  /*changed*/
}
#home-img-blocks {
  width: 100%;
  height: 750px;
}
.home-img-block {
  width: 33.33%;
  /*height: 100%;*/
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
.home-img-block:hover .overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.home-img-block:after {
  content: attr(data-content);
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 20px 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
.home-img-block:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.home-img-block img {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;  /* Firefox */
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;  /* IE 9 */
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;  /* Opera */
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.home-img-block:hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transform: scale(1.25);  /* Firefox */
  -ms-transform: scale(1.25);  /* IE 9 */
  -o-transform: scale(1.25);  /* Opera */
  transform: scale(1.25);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 33.33%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.home-img-block img.wide {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.home-img-block img.tall {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
#home-img-block-wording-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.home-img-wording-blocks {
  width: 100%;  /* changed was 33%*/
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.home-img-wording-block-title {
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
}
.home-img-wording-block-description {
  padding: 25px 50px 0 50px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #5d5d5d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home-img-block-section">
  <div id="home-img-blocks">
    <div data-content="FIND OUT MORE" class="home-img-block">
      <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test1.jpg">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="home-img-wording-blocks">
        <div class="home-img-wording-block-title">WEB DESIGN</div>
        <div class="home-img-wording-block-description">The OD team can see your web design visions brought to life, creating a site that promotes your uniqueness through specific functionalities and features.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-content="FIND OUT MORE" class="home-img-block">
      <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test2new.jpg">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="home-img-wording-blocks">
        <div class="home-img-wording-block-title">ECOMMERCE</div>
        <div class="home-img-wording-block-description">Custom built solutions catered towards you end goal.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-content="FIND OUT MORE" class="home-img-block">
      <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test3new.jpg">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="home-img-wording-blocks">
        <div class="home-img-wording-block-title">MARKETING STRATEGIES</div>
        <div class="home-img-wording-block-description">MARKETING STRATEGIES</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Too many unclosed DIV tags. Use it properly

Comment: @Stark: Are you sure there are unclosed `div` tags? I don't see any unclosed tags and if otherwise, the snippet formatter wouldn't produce a properly formatted output.

Comment: @Stark What are you talking about? Learn how to read code. There aren't any unclosed div tags.

Comment: @Becky: I have modified the content slightly to make the "question" more obvious because some users were complaining that it is unclear. I didn't think it was unclear even in the first place though. Hope you don't mind the edit. If you feel it is superfluous or not helpful, please feel free to rollback :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the `img` and `div.overlay` alone into a `div` of their own. As per code provided in question, the overlay element is positioned absolutely in relation to the `div.home-img-block` element which houses the `div.homve-img-wording-blocks` also and so, when `height:100%` is set, it means the full height of `div.home-img-block` element (which includes the height occupied by the description text also).

Similarly the `img` also derives its height from the parent and so `max-height: 100%` means that it can expand till it fills up the entire parent's height (including the description). But the scale transform that is applied on the element is increasing its height only by 25%, so its zoomed height is not more than the height of the parent container and hence it doesn't overflow.

When you put the `img` and `.overlay` into a container element of their own, their height is not derived based on the `.home-img-block` (which includes the description text). Since we haven't set any height explicitly on this wrapper element, it gets just enough height to fit the contents and so the overlay and the image doesn't spill over on to the area occupied by the description.

```js
$('.home-img-block img').addClass(function() {
  return (this.width / this.height > 1) ? 'wide' : 'tall';
});
```

```css
#home-img-block-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 900px;
}
#home-img-blocks {
  width: 100%;
  height: 750px;
}
.home-img-block {
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.home-img-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.home-img-container:hover .overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.home-img-container:after {
  content: attr(data-content);
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 20px 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
.home-img-container:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.home-img-block img {
  display: block;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.home-img-container:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.25);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 33.33%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.home-img-block img.wide {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.home-img-block img.tall {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
#home-img-block-wording-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.home-img-wording-blocks {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.home-img-wording-block-title {
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
}
.home-img-wording-block-description {
  padding: 25px 50px 0 50px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #5d5d5d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home-img-block-section">
  <div id="home-img-blocks">
    <div class="home-img-block">
      <div data-content="FIND OUT MORE" class='home-img-container'>
        <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test1.jpg">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="home-img-wording-blocks">
        <div class="home-img-wording-block-title">WEB DESIGN</div>
        <div class="home-img-wording-block-description">The OD team can see your web design visions brought to life, creating a site that promotes your uniqueness through specific functionalities and features.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="home-img-block">
      <div data-content="FIND OUT MORE" class='home-img-container'>
        <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test2new.jpg">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="home-img-wording-blocks">
        <div class="home-img-wording-block-title">ECOMMERCE</div>
        <div class="home-img-wording-block-description">Custom built solutions catered towards you end goal.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="home-img-block">
      <div data-content="FIND OUT MORE" class='home-img-container'>
        <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test3new.jpg">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="home-img-wording-blocks">
        <div class="home-img-wording-block-title">MARKETING STRATEGIES</div>
        <div class="home-img-wording-block-description">MARKETING STRATEGIES</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation! This works wonderfully. Great answer!

Comment: Quick question regarding this. Do you know why my cursor would be changing to a pointer under the image?

Comment: @Becky That would be because we have a cursor:pointer defined within the .home-img-block selector. If it needn't change then just remove it :)

Comment: Well I want the cursor to be a pointer. Just not under the image. I just want it to be a pointer over the image. I tried adding it to : `.home-img-block img`, but it did nothing.

Comment: @Becky: Ok, in that case add it to the `.home-img-container` selector (I've updated it in the answer).

Answer (score 1):

`element.width` and `element.height` are not real properties and would each be undefined

Try

```
$('.home-img-block img').addClass(function() {
  return ($(this).width() / $(this).height() > 1) ? 'wide' : 'tall';
});
```

Comment: That didn't make a difference. It is only when I am hovering over the image, that I see issues.